# Flash - how to turn off the "Enable hardware acceleration" window?

Tags: html, flash, wmode

We have a piece of swf embedded for recording (the [wami-recorder](http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/)). 
The issue is that some clients experience that the window for enabling hardware acceleration *always* pops up.

[image]

Instead of this, there should be a popup for enabling recording (the privacy tab), and that would've been  OK - but that's not the window displayed (the mic tab here is just for volume, not what I need)

Do you have any clue as to what's going on here? Why is this 'enable hardware acceleration' showing and how to hide it?

The swf is embedded somewhat like this (stripped down):

```
var flashVars = {
        visible : false,
        loadedCallback : initfn
    }
var params = {
        allowScriptAccess : "always"
    }
params.wmode = "transparent";
var version = '10.0.0';

Wami.swfobject.embedSWF(_options.swfUrl, id, 
       214, 137, version, null, flashVars, params);
```

Comment: Can I just say that I am having the exact same problem. I would beg that you offer a bounty. This is such a piece of work. Do you have the issue that that window will not go away even if you hit close?

Comment: It appears this 'stripped down' version of Flash privacy panel is only visible when in incognito mode. Though I believe to switch to the microphone tab in this case, you have to do something in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue when you are using the wami swf within an iframe on Safari / Mac OS X. Safari unfortunately disables certain features in this situation.

A workaround can be to redirect Safari users out of the iframe and/or show a popup (which is also outside of the iframe).